# Postgres sql return uuid after insert into table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, variables

I  am doing insert into one table record and generating UUID, how do I return this UUID to use in another part of my function?

function

```
do $$
begin 
 insert into table_1 values (uuid,,,,,,n);

-- need the result of this insert load into variable uuid_customer to reuse later

insert into tabel_2 (uuid,uuid_customer,,,,,,n );
end
```

in MSSQL I can use output, but what about Postgres

> INSERT INTO table (name) OUTPUT Inserted.ID VALUES('bob');

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
WITH list AS
( insert into table_1 
  values (uuid,,,,,,n)
  returning uuid
)
SELECT uuid INTO uuid_customer ;
```